# Laravel , Blade & React js add the meta tag for rendering on server side SEO

Tags: reactjs, laravel, seo, laravel-blade, react-helmet

I am trying to render the meta tags on the server-side. so i can see this output on share link like this: [image]

I tried React-Helmet but it's only rendering on load.

My Controller

```
public function home()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

Blade:

```
  <div class="post-list" id="booksList"></div>
```

React Module:

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

export default function MetaTags(props) {
const { title , metas } = props

return (
    <div className="application">
    <Helmet>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>{ title ?? '' }-NicelyLogic</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="language" content="English" />
        <meta name="title" content={title ?? ''+'-NicelyLogic'} />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        {
            metas.map(meta => {
               return (<meta name={meta.name} content={meta.content} />)
            })
        }
    </Helmet>
    </div>
)
```

}

It's working 100% correct when we load the site on browser that's mean it's only rendering metas on user side. I want to render the site on server side. So it become user friendly.

Comment: There are SSR instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet but this requires you to set-up SSR for your project to begin with which is not a painless task. You might find a functioning 3rd party library though if you are lucky

Comment: there is not easy to get this done?

Comment: The idea is that on each request you need to call the nodejs binary to run the script that would render your ssr code and somehow get that result and put it in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use React to control meta data display on search engine, because js handle these thing after your root view is rendered. Try to change your root view instead by passing variables to your root view (`app.blade.php`):

```html
<meta name="title" content="{{ $title ?? 'App title' }}">
<meta name="description" content="{{ $description ?? 'App desc' }}">
```

Share these variables to view in your controller methods:

```php
...
  $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
  view()->share([
    'title' => $post->title,
    'description' => $post->desc,
  ]);
...
```

Reload and view source, you can see that they has been rendered on first server load time.
I'm using `Laravel` + `ReactJs` with `InertiaJs`.